# Number of different pizzas that you can make while choosing k toppings out of available n.

Tags: combinatorics

In a pizzeria you can order a pizza in the following way:

You can pay $2$ dollars for crust of the pizza.

You can add a topping to the crust of the pizza for $1$ dollar each. Pizzeria offers n different toppings.

You have $k+2$ dollars and you want to spend all this money on pizza so you pay $2$ dollars for the crust and exactly $k$ dollars for $k$ toppings. **How many different pizzas you can order?**

Note that you can buy use single topping multiple times and the order of the toppings does not matter. For example crust+(cheese, cheese, ham, cheese) is a pizza with $4$ toppings and is the same as crust+(ham, cheese, cheese, cheese).

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'll try to beat the crowd crying "[Stars and Bars](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stars_and_bars_%28combinatorics%29)" here.

You'll need the crust, order the possible toppings and start at the first one. Then repeatedly decide either "one more of this topping", or "move on to the next topping". Once you've either spent all your money or reached the last topping there is nothing more to decide; repeat "move on to the next topping" in the former case or "one more of this topping" in the latter case anyway, to arrive at a situation where you have both spent your money and reached the last topping. All in all you've said "one more of this topping" $k$ times, and "move on to the next topping" $n-1$ times (if there were $n$ toppings). All in all there were $n-1+k$ choices, of which $k$ of the first kind, for $$\binom{n-1+k}k$$ possibilities.

Comment: Thank you so much, explanation is very good and I understand it now :P

Answer (score 2):

In this problem you don't care about the order in which the toppings are chosen and repeated toppings are allowed. Thus this is a combination of a multiset. To count combinations of a multiset use the formula
$$\frac{(n+k-1)!}{n!(k-1)!}$$
where $n$ is the number of things you want to choose and $k$ the number of distinct objects to choose from.